# build Windows Phone 8 application in Xamerin

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am installed XamarinInstaller which include Xamerin for Visual Studio. It contains iOS and Android (but not Windows Phone 8). How can I use Xamerin to build Windows Phone 8 application ?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin tools only help you build iOS and Android apps. To build WP8 apps, download the Windows Phone SDK from developer.windowsphone.com

Comment: in documentation note that Xamerin is crossplatform framwork for iOS,Android and Windows Phone

Answer (score 0):

You should just do it in Visual Studio 2012 with the Windows Phone SDK as the Xamarin folks recommend. You can get a free version here: [Visual Studio Express 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2012-express)

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,This is a common problem.....When Win Phone SDK is not installed on your PC ,your Xamerinapp.WinPhone project is not created.All you need to do is to install sdk from Microsoft official website and you are done!!!!!
But please note one thing that you cant use Xamerin studio to develop Winphone App...you must have VS2012/2013 on your PC.